# Best way to compare XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, difference

I'm looking for the best way to compare two XML files for difference using C#. Like say for example if I have two XMLs A and B like this:

**XML A**

```
<data:TR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pd="http://www.ascentn.com/bpm/XMLSchema">
  <data:processFields />
  <data:formFields>
    <data:TextBox1>111</data:TextBox1>
    <data:TextBox2>222</data:TextBox2>
    <data:TextBox3>3333</data:TextBox3>
    <data:Repeat1_Repeat>
      <data:Repeat1>
        <data:TextBox4>444</data:TextBox4>
        <data:TextBox5>555</data:TextBox5>
      </data:Repeat1>
    </data:Repeat1_Repeat>
  </data:formFields>
</data:TR>
```

**XML B**

```
<data:TR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pd="http://www.ascentn.com/bpm/XMLSchema">
  <data:processFields />
  <data:formFields>
    <data:TextBox1>111</data:TextBox1>
    <data:TextBox2>aaa</data:TextBox2>
    <data:TextBox3>3333</data:TextBox3>
    <data:Repeat1_Repeat>
      <data:Repeat1>
        <data:TextBox4>bbb</data:TextBox4>
        <data:TextBox5>555</data:TextBox5>
      </data:Repeat1>
      <data:Repeat1>
        <data:TextBox4>ccc</data:TextBox4>
        <data:TextBox5>ddd</data:TextBox5>
      </data:Repeat1>
    </data:Repeat1_Repeat>
  </data:formFields>
</data:TR>
```

I'm looking to get only the different between the two XML files, like in this case it would be TextBox2 and TextBox4 and one full node for Repeat1_Repeat.

Is there a easy way to get this? Maybe use some framework? I'm using .NET 4.5.2 so anything recent would work too!

Thanks!

EDIT : Oh and also, I need it to work for n-level of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think **XMLDiff** is the best way. No framework needed. As seen on MSDN:

> By using the XMLDiff class, the programmer is able to determine if the
>   two files are in fact different based on the conditions that are
>   important to their application. The programmer is able to ignore
>   changes that are only superficial (for example, different prefixes for
>   same namespace). XMLPatch then provides the ability to update the
>   original XML by applying only the changes that matter to the original
>   XML.

You should check it out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, I did check XMLDiff but does it support n levels of nesting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Paste Special**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate classes for your XML.

Then you can deserialise your xml to create an instance of your code generated class.

So for two xml files; you can create two objects like `xmlObject1` and `xmlObject2`.

Then you can use [**CompareObject**](https://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/) to identify the difference between two objects.

Comment: Hi Kosala, I believe you're referring to the manual way of comparing XML files? I need it to be automated in a program.

Comment: @CRMJunkie What do you mean by manual way? We are not here to discuss manual processes. Have you read the articles in those links? Let me know if you don't understand them. I will publish some sample codes.